# Display current month total days

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to show current month total days on a visualforce page in a table of one coulmn..How can I do that like in below?

1/02/2014,Monday
2/02/2014,Tuesday
3/02/2014,Wednesday
4/02/2014,Thursday
5/02/2014,Firday
.
.
.
.
So on upto 30 days

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

This Apex code will produce the set of dates:

```
Integer year = 2014;
Integer month = 2;
Date[] dates = new Date[] {};
Integer daysInMonth = Date.daysInMonth(year, month);
for (Integer day = 1; day <= daysInMonth; day++) {
    dates.add(Date.newInstance(year, month, day));
}
```

and this Visualforce will [format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) those dates:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!dates}" var="d">
    <apex:column>
        <apex:outputText value="{0, date, d'/'MM'/'yyyy,EEEE}">
            <apex:param value="{!d}" /> 
        </apex:outputText>
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```